# Managing API keys for GCM without Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have an Android app with push notifications send by GCM. I set this up a few years ago. All works fine.

Now i want to manage my API keys but the Google Play Developer Console is not showing the API keys anymore, like they use to do. They always link to the new Firebase API.

I tried https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials but the new API keys won't be accepted by Google and the old one doesn't show up there. That's maybe because I can't link it to my Android app.

Where can I still manage my GCM API keys? I want to create a new one but I don't want to migrate my project to Firebase. Is this still possible?

Comment: Same problem here. incredibly annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Go to [Android Start](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start) and click [Get a Configuration File](http://imgur.com/PnJTXjN). There you'll be able to generate GCM API keys. The same goes if you're using iOS.

Comment: the second link is broken and i cant find the configuration file in the first link

Answer (score 1):

If you are like me and gave in to **FCM**, you can still use the **GCM project identity**: its under console, FCM settings and contains the server key and identity.

Comment: + for "gave up" to FCM. I could not find my keys unless sign up to fcm.

Answer (score 1):

Visit this link and follow the steps 
    https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android
Download the google-service.json file, it contains the keys you need